# Why does my partner community show up like Classic on SF1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, partner-communities

We have built a partner community using the Visualforce & Tabs template. We now want to find out if Salesforce1 is a viable option to perform certain actions our users want to do from a mobile device.

I've worked through all steps from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_access_in_salesforce1.htm&language=en_US&type=0), and I'm able to log in, but I am then **redirected to the Classic interface**:

[image: SF1]

PS1: Documentation states the following, but doing so also just rerenders the page in Classic in my browser (while this does work for internal users):

> Without this setting, community members must append /one/one.app to
>   the community URL (for example,
>   https://universaltelco.force.com/customer/one/one.app) to access the
>   community via Salesforce1 from a supported mobile browser.

PS2: Not sure if related at all, but I cannot find [this setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_s1_settings.htm&type=0) anywhere. We are using a custom login Visualforce page and redirecting to a next Visualforce page after that, which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution seems to be a bit more complicated (and more custom than you'd expect)

Answer based on this document: [Code implementation considerations when using custom Login, Landing or Authentication pages for Salesforce1 Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Salesforce1-Code-implementation-to-consider-when-using-custom-Login-and-authentication-pages-for-Salesforce1-communities&language=en_US&type=1)

**STEP 1** the controller apex class that gets the landing page after login should have the following code added:

```
public PageReference forwardToStartPage() {

    return Network.communitiesLanding();

}
```

**STEP 2** the custom VisualForce page that handles the communities landing, in the first line of code

```
action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}"
```

AND you must implement something like this (and this is where the documentation fails because the code sample doesn't compile nor does it support Android or anything else besides iphone.

```
public with sharing class CommunitiesLandingController {

    // Code to invoke on page load.
    public PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {

        if(UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Guest'){
            return new PageReference('dealers/DC_Custom_Login_Page');
        }

        //Get useragent
        String userAgent = System.currentPageReference().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');

        // Regex for useragent
        Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune');
        Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(useragent);

        if(myMatcher.find()){
            return new PageReference('/one/one.app');
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }


    // Code we will invoke on page load.
    public PageReference forwardToStartPage() {
        return Network.communitiesLanding();
    }

    public CommunitiesLandingController() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your **PS2**:

As your link states:

> Easily link to Visualforce pages from other Visualforce pages in Salesforce1 by selecting the checkbox under Salesforce1 Settings for Communities in **Communities Settings**.

This checkbox can be found in *Communities Settings*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that one. It is not solving my problem though :-(